# Regex expression for a discord username

Tags: regex, discord

I cannot seem to find it perfectly, so that's why I'm asking here.
What would be the regex expression for the new discord usernames ?

From what I know, they must not contain "@", "#", ":", "```" or "discord".
The username cannot be exactly "everyone" nor "here".
Whitespaces cannot be put twice in a row, your username cannot start nor end with a whitespace, and I guess that it checks the "only whitespace" case.

I've already tried something, but I cannot really conclude

````js
/^(?!(?:@|```|:|#|discord))$/ // For the "not contain"
/^([^\s].*[^\s])$/ // For the not start/end with whitespace
````

Comment: https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/12620128861463-New-Usernames-Display-Names#h_01GXPQAGG6W477HSC5SR053QG1

Comment: That's sure better info for the specific expression thanks :)
I'll probably still struggle to get the regex

Comment: How do you want to implement the "Usernames used to impersonate Discord, Discord staff, or Discord system messages, used to impersonate an individual, group, or organization, that attack other people or promote hate, that contain sexually explicit language" restrictions? Other than that, `^(?=.{2,32}$)\.?[a-z0-9_]+(?:\.[a-z0-9_]+)*\.?$` should do the basic validation. To avoid `here`, add a negative lookahead: `^(?=.{2,32}$)(?!(?:everyone|here)$)\.?[a-z0-9_]+(?:\.[a-z0-9_]+)*\.?$`

Comment: I guess I'll pass this one, I'll probably just include some of the words in the "everyone" and "here" list of items

Comment: The updated version is perfect thanks :D

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think you can post an answer here.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
^(?=.{2,32}$)(?!(?:everyone|here)$)\.?[a-z0-9_]+(?:\.[a-z0-9_]+)*\.?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EtOB3i/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{2,32}$)` - the string must contain two to thirty-two chars
- `(?!(?:everyone|here)$)` - the string cannot be equal to "everyone" or "here"
- `\.?` - an optional dot
- `[a-z0-9_]+` - one or more lowercase letters/digits/underscores
- `(?:\.[a-z0-9_]+)*` - zero or more sequences of a `.` and then one or more lowercase letters/digits/underscores
- `\.?` - an optional dot
- `$` - end of string.